# Script de windows para detener un servicio

Tags: windows

Tengo un portàtil con S.O windows7 profesional con todos los updates al dia y cada vez que enciendo el portátil el servicio "svchost" me consume 250mb de ram , manualmente desde el taskmgr voy al ejecutable y en los servicios de windows uso la opción de "parar servicio" en el servicio "upnphost" y dicha ram deja de crecer , esto lo hago cada dia de forma manual y me gustaría saber si alguien sabría hacerlo en un script de windows para poder ponerlo en el inicio del sistema y olvidarme de ello.

Gracias,

Comment: Estas seguro que el proceso se llama "svchost"?

Answer (score 1):

Podrías irte a "servicios" en Windows (Ejecutar -> services.msc) y deshabilitar el servicio, sin embargo es un servicio de Windows que para algo debe de servir, no? Ya te las has preguntado? Puedes deshabilatarlo desde ahí y ya no se ejecutara en el inicia, **pero eso tendrá consecuencias**. Ej: No poder mandar archivos por el Grupo Hogar.

[Aqui](https://answers.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/servicio-svchost-consume-el-100-del-procesador/7a75b6d8-7df0-440f-b1c6-b221d92b0c3e) esta la ayuda de windows sobre este problema.